# Regional issue with Jquery datepicker MVC

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to resolve regional issue (Italy) but with no success, the script in my View is:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('.datefield').datepicker({
                startDate: "-3d",
                maxViewMode: 3,
                todayBtn: "linked",
                multidate: false,
                autoclose: true,
                todayHighlight: true,
                toggleActive: true,
                FormData: "yyyy-MM-dd",
                regional:"it"
            });
            //$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);
            //$('.datefield').datepicker();
        });
</script>
```

but the datepicker is in english. I don't understand. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to ensure you include jQuery, jQueryUI and the i18n library for jQueryUI too, all in the correct order. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.datefield').datepicker({
    startDate: "-3d",
    maxViewMode: 3,
    todayBtn: "linked",
    multidate: false,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true,
    toggleActive: true,
    FormData: "yyyy-MM-dd"
  });
  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['it']);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" />
<input type="text" class="datefield" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rory, everything runs perfectly if I put the code in the view, but if I use it in the _Layout regional settings don't run. I don't understand the importance of correct order, could you explain it please?

Comment: A little late replying, but the order is important as the scripts have dependencies on each other. i18n relies on jQueryUI which relies on jQuery.